# outlook view unique content emails having same subject

Tags: mysql, email, search, outlook

Is there any query to find distinct messages in mailbox with same subject and has different contents inside the mail body in outlook?
we can write queries in outlook to find mails but i need to know whether we have query to find distinct mails since it is available in SQL queries by using distinct keyword

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

No, your code would need to find messages by subject first, then decide what constitutes uniqueness and process the messages accordingly.